# Multiple allow-origin headers

Tags: ajax, iis

I'm trying to make a simple ajax request, but get an error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:52007, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:52007' is therefore not allowed access."

Request:

```html
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
```

As I understand the error occurs because response contains two 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers: one for my machine - 'localhost:52007' and an other one is '*'.

The last one '*' is added automatically by IIS by HTTP Response Headers section(there is a rule to always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin='*'). Unfortunately I can't change that

After I looked on request via Fiddler I saw that it contains Access-Control-Allow-Origin='localhost'. It looks like on the server this header is copied to response and also  Access-Control-Allow-Origin='*' is added because of the rule.

So, what can I do in this situation? Can I remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin='localhost' from my request? Or maybe if I  change it's value from 'localhost' to '*' it would not be copied to response. But how can I do that?